# Adding Java code formatting rules to Sonarqube

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting, sonarqube

In Eclipse we add a formatting.xml files to check the Java code formatting.

In Eclipse go to Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter and we enter the formatting.xml

Inside the formatting.xml file we have several Java code formatting rules:

```
<profiles version="10">
<profile name="JavaFormatter" version="10">
    <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.align_type_members_on_columns" value="false"/>
    <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_arguments_in_allocation_expression" value="16"/>
    <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_arguments_in_enum_constant" value="16"/>
    <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_arguments_in_explicit_constructor_call" value="16"/>
    <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_arguments_in_method_invocation" value="16"/>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

Is there a way of adding these rules to SonarQube 4.1.1?
I have already imported our checkstyle rules, I just need to add the code formatting rules.

Answer (score 1):

No. It's not currently possible.